# Notes error: JVM: Attempt to retrieve Java agent attachments failed

Tags: java, jdbc, lotus

I'm having a problem when using a JDBC connection to POSTGREE database. Lotus appears on the console the following error:

```
16/02/2012 15:34:36   Agent  error: JVMDUMP006I Processando Evento de Dump "systhrow",  detalhe "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError" - Aguarde. 
16/02/2012 15:34:36   Agent  error: JVMDUMP032I  
16/02/2012 15:34:36   Agent  error: JVMDUMP010I Snap Dump gravado em /local/notesdata/Snap.20120216.153437.18971.0001.trc 
16/02/2012 15:34:36   Agent  error: JVMDUMP032I  
16/02/2012 15:34:36   Agent  error: JVMDUMP010I Heap Dump gravado em /local/notesdata/heapdump.20120216.153437.18971.0002.phd 
16/02/2012 15:34:36   Agent  error: JVMDUMP032I  
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: JVMDUMP010I Java Dump gravado em /local/notesdata/javacore.20120216.153437.18971.0003.txt 
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: JVMDUMP013I Evento de Dump Processado "systhrow", detalhe "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError". 
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: Exce∑∫∑˙o no encadeamento "Thread-60"
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error:  at 
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: java.util.Arrays
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: .
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: copyOfRange
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: (
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: Arrays.java
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: :
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: 4
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: 0
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: 5
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: 4
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: )
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error:  at 
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: java.util.Arrays
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: .
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: copyOf
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: (
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: Arrays.java
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: :
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: 3
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: 7
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: 8
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: 6
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: )
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error:  at 
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: .
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: write
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: (
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: ByteArrayOutputStream.java
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: :
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: 9
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: 3
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: )
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error:  at 
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: lotus.domino.ClassHashtable
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: .
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: explodeArchive
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: (Unknown Source)
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error:  at 
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: lotus.domino.ClassHashtable
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: .
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: addAttachment
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: (Unknown Source)
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error:  at 
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: lotus.domino.AgentLoader
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: .
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: addAttachment
16/02/2012 15:34:37   Agent  error: (Unknown Source)
16/02/2012 15:34:37   JVM: The addAttachment (Ljava/lang/String;[B)V() method failed.
```

Cleaned up the exception is:

```
JVMDUMP006I Processando Evento de Dump "systhrow",  detalhe "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError" - Aguarde. 
JVMDUMP032I  
JVMDUMP010I Snap Dump gravado em /local/notesdata/Snap.20120216.153437.18971.0001.trc 
JVMDUMP032I  
JVMDUMP010I Heap Dump gravado em /local/notesdata/heapdump.20120216.153437.18971.0002.phd 
JVMDUMP032I  
JVMDUMP010I Java Dump gravado em /local/notesdata/javacore.20120216.153437.18971.0003.txt 
JVMDUMP013I Evento de Dump Processado "systhrow", detalhe "java/lang/OutOfMemoryError". 
Exce∑∫∑˙o no encadeamento "Thread-60"

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:4054)
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3786)
 at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
 at lotus.domino.ClassHashtable.explodeArchive(Unknown Source)
 at lotus.domino.ClassHashtable.addAttachment(Unknown Source)
 at lotus.domino.AgentLoader.addAttachment(Unknown Source)
JVM: The addAttachment (Ljava/lang/String;[B)V() method failed.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the important part is this:

```
lotus.domino.AgentLoader.addAttachment(Unknown Source)
```

AgentLoader.addAttachment is a method that runs when your agent is first starting to be executed. What it does is checks your agent for any JARs contained within the agent and downloads (if on client) and detaches them to the system before loading them into the JVM.

When your agent completes it cleans these up. So every time the agent runs it has to do this step.

This error can occur for a few reasons.

**Reason 1: (main one)**

There is overhead both in network and processing to detach load/jars to the system. If you are under a heavy load it is possible that the system does not have enough memory to complete the action.

**Reason 2:**

Some third party APIs will not work in this fashion. Google API for example I have seen fail in this way.

**Reason 3:**

There was a memory leak in V8.0 (SPR KPAL6YWRN9) in relation to web services. This has since been fixed.

**How to resolve the issue:**

Remove any jars you have contained in your agent and drop them into the jvm/lib/ext folder. You will need to restart Domino/Notes. The jars will then be loaded by the JVM only once.

If you are still getting the error at that point, then is more likely another Java agent is not cleaning up correctly after itself.

Comment: when i remove jars from the agent it wont compile.!! it is not able to find related jars

Comment: @Himanshu.MarJAVA You are using R6 IIRC? I am not sure if this is the same (it's been so long).

Comment: Yes.. I Am using R6. Well the compiling issue was resolved by restarting the server. BUT I am still getiing this error. Do you know any means to diagnose this by analysing the heapdump file?

Comment: Sorry. :/ I haven't touched R6 since mid-2008 (end of life date).